# Swift 3 changing the title of a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton

I have been looking around the web and I am unable to find a solution for my problem. I want my "START" button text to change to "RESTART" once the game has ended. **If any additional information is needed please let me know.** Thanks, all help is appreciated. Below is my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var gameOver = false
var stopFuncs = false

var gameTimer = Timer()
var counter = 10

var selected = "NONE"
var score = 0
var colour = "NONE"


@IBOutlet weak var colourLabel: UILabel!

let colourProvider = ColourProvider()

@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    colour = colourProvider.randomColour()
    print(colour)
    colourLabel.text = colour


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!

func updateCounter() {
    if counter >= 0 {
        counterLabel.text = String(counter)
        counter -= 1
    }
}

@IBAction func startButton() {
    gameOver = false
    counter = 10
    stopFuncs = false
    var _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


@IBAction func greenButton() {
    if stopFuncs { return }
    compareColours(selectedColour: "GREEN")
    changeColourLabel()
    colourLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
}

@IBAction func blueButton() {
    if stopFuncs { return }
    compareColours(selectedColour: "BLUE")
    changeColourLabel()
    colourLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
}

@IBAction func yellowButton() {
    if stopFuncs { return }
    compareColours(selectedColour: "YELLOW")
    changeColourLabel()
    colourLabel.textColor = UIColor.yellow
}

@IBAction func pinkButton() {
    if stopFuncs { return }
    compareColours(selectedColour: "GREEN")
    changeColourLabel()
    colourLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
}

func compareColours(selectedColour: String) {
    if gameOver == false && counter >= 1 {
        if selectedColour == colour {
            score += 1
            let scoreString = String(score)
            scoreLabel.text = scoreString
        }
        else {
            gameOver = true
        }
    }
    else {
        stopFuncs = true


    }
}

func changeColourLabel() {
    colour = colourProvider.randomColour()
    colourLabel.text = colour
    print(colour)
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button needs to be an IBOutlet rather than an IBAction. When you ctrl-drag from Interface Builder to your code, make sure you select the 'Outlet' option as shown below:

[image: IB - Code illustration]

Then you can change the button title like this:

```
else {
    startButton.setTitle("Button Title", for: .normal)
    stopFuncs = true
}
```

Comment: Hi, that still does not work for me. I am getting this error message https://gyazo.com/497f8a364581d40b3cafc5c7f1fb46a3

Comment: Show the code where you instantiate the button. Doesn't sound like you're doing it properly

Comment: @IBAction func startButton() {

}

Comment: Hi, I just updated my button code so that when you click it, it executes some code. If I change it to an outlet will this still work? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @IBAction func startButton() {
        gameOver = false
        counter = 10
        stopFuncs = false
        var _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

Comment: No but you can have both an outlet and an action in the same class. For clarity, I suggest naming the outlet `startButton` and then the action `startButtonPressed`.

Answer (score 3):

You already have `IBOutlets` to some of your labels.

For buttons you may need to set up both an `IBaction` and an `IBOutlet`.

An `IBOutlet` is a thing. A noun. It's a reference to a view object.

An `IBAction` is a verb. An action. It's code that gets called when something happens to a `UIControl` (tapping a button, moving a slider, changing the selected value on a segmented control, etc.)

The `IBaction` is a function that gets called when the user interacts with a control (For buttons you almost always link the action to the .touchUpInside control event.)

Naming your actions with names like `pinkButton` is a bad idea, and leads to confusion. I suggest renaming your actions to verbs, like `handlePinkButton` (or perhaps "pinkButtonTapped", but I prefer action names to be verbs.)

Note that when you rename an `IBAction` and/or `IBOutlet` you have to go into IB (IB = Interface Builder), select the connections inspector, remove the now-incorrect IBOutlet/IBAction and control-drag from the object to the updated outlet/action.

If you don't do that you'll get very confusing crashes at runtime:

- Renaming `IBOutlets` in code without also changing them in IB gives the error "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key old_outlet_name" (where "old_outlet_name" will be the old name of your outlet.) when you try to load the view controller from the storyboard. Renaming actions )
- Renaming `IBActions` in code without also changing them in IB gives an error "unrecognized selector sent to instance big_hex_number" when you try to tap the button (or trigger the action for other controls.)

You should open your storyboard in the main editor and open the source in the assistant editor, then control-drag from your button in IB into your source code just below your other outlet at the top of your class.